# jQuery chaining faster than separate statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, method-chaining

Is it faster to write separate calls to the jQuery function, or to use a single chain? If an added explanation of why one is faster than the other, it will be greatly appreciated :-)

An example:

```
$('#blah_id').niftyjQueryMethod1().niftyjQueryMethod2();
```

is faster/slower than

```
$('#blah_id').niftyjQueryMethod1();
$('#blah_id').niftyjQueryMethod2();
```

Comment: second case is making selector run twice. even if there would be caching, first case looks faster

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, chaining is faster.

```
// Example 1
$('#blah_id').niftyjQueryMethod1().niftyjQueryMethod2();

// Example 2
$('#blah_id').niftyjQueryMethod1();
$('#blah_id').niftyjQueryMethod2();
```

In example 1, the call to create the jQuery object (`$('#blah_id')`) is only made once.  In example 2, it is made twice.  This means the second call will be slower.

If you don't want to put them all in a chain, you can cache the selection in a variable:

```
var blah = $('#blah_id');
blah.niftyjQueryMethod1();
blah.niftyjQueryMethod2();
```

Presuming that the methods don't affect what elements are present in the selection selection (like, for example, `parent`, `find`, or `filter` do) this will be pretty much exactly the same as example 1.

Comment: I'm showing that chaining is 3X faster (webkit or firefox) with event delegation and a reasonably complex page. http://jsperf.com/jquery-chaining-with-event-delegation

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
$('#blah_id').niftyjQueryMethod1().niftyjQueryMethod2();
```

Probably is faster than this:

```
$('#blah_id').niftyjQueryMethod1(); $('#blah_id').niftyjQueryMethod2();
```

But not because of the chaining. It's because there's a cost to the selector lookup.

This:

```
var $blah = $('#blah_id');
$blah.niftyjQueryMethod1();
$blah.niftyjQueryMethod2();
```

probably has no appreciable difference in speed from the first example.

Comment: Also a very good answer. Wish I could set both as answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First one is faster. In the second selector is creating a jQuery object twice. If `$('#blah_id')` was cached and stored as a variable `var $blah = $('#blah_id')` and then using in your second selector as $blah and not `$('#blah_id')` then it would make no real difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, chaining is faster, because the found DOMElement (via the `$('#blah_id')`) is only directly passed form function to function.

If you seperate them, the DOMElement has to be found again and again and again. Every `$("selector")` is evil. Try to avoid them as often as possible.

You can even set references to the previosuly found objets:

```
var myElement = $('#blah_id');

myElement.doSomething();
```